# How to pass UILabel with NSUserdefualts?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to pass the value of `UILabel` with `NSUserDefaults` .
At the first viewController I have a picker and the picked item is a `UILabel` string. 
In the second viewController I want the item that has been chosen from the picker to be simply displayed as a `UILabel` string .

How can I do this with `NSUserDefaults`, I know how do it with `UITextField` but it does not work for me with `UILabel`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you want to pass the `UILabel` itself, or the text shown *in* the label?

Comment: Both I think? I want to pass the Uilabel

Comment: I don't see difference between UITextField and UILabel, at least provide some code to see where you have this issue

Comment: So you're using `NSUserDefaults` to pass values between view controllers?

Comment: why do you want to pass a `UILabel` to the `NSUserDefault`? please post some code about what you are doing.

Comment: You can't pass a `UILabel`, but you can store the content of the `label.text` property. But maybe it is better to not use `NSUserDefaults` for data passing bewteen controllers...

Comment: I'm not home right know I'm with my phone when I get home I will post my code.

Comment: You should tell us how you instantiate each view controller, what the sequence of events in the program is, and how your storyboard is setup.  You actually need advice as to how to structure a typical iOS GUI app. Speaking from experience, you want to try to do things as close as you can to the way that Apple intended, or you end up doing a lot more work in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

To store the value of your `UILabel` to `NSUserDefaults` you can use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:label.text forKey:@"myLabelText"];
```

To get the value stored on `NSUserDefaults` and pass it to label you can use

```
label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myLabelText"];
```

## BUT

`NSUserDefaults` is not recommended to store dynamic properties. The easiest solution for you should be to pass data between different viewControllers:

- [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)